# upgrade to 12.04.2 and all *-quantal packages

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and upgraded. I noticed lots of packages with -quantal suffix (kernel, xorg stack, drivers, etc.), which is included in 12.04.2 upgrade.  How to easily upgrade all of my installed packages to *-quantal equivalent?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

**However you are on newest stable Ubuntu edition. This command will allow you to switch to DEVELOPMENT version of Ubuntu!**

**Explanation of *-quantal packages present in precise edition**

Ubuntu updates are split into few categories ranging from security, to back-ported.

Back ported describe package with version of software that will land in next Ubuntu version, but is deemed stable enough and can bring enough value to Ubuntu users that packages for earlier versions are released.

You can check settings in Update Manager or in Ubuntu Software Center, for all options.

Each update category is optional (yes you can even disable security updates, but its not an good idea).

All that mean that you can benefit from newest software versions any Ubuntu can offer without potential troubles of using development version of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu will provide you with notification when Ubuntu 13.04 is ready. Then you will be able to update to Quantal without trouble!

Comment: mate, I don't want to upgrade my LTS to Quantal. In Precise' repos there are packages with *-quantal suffix e.g. [linux-generic-lts-quantal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise-updates/linux-generic-lts-quantal) I want to upgrade all my installed packages to *-quantal equivalents if there are any. That is if I have the package linux-generic-lts installed so it's upgraded to linux-generic-lts-quantal.

Comment: Ubuntu software center -> settings -> check "Backported" check box. Update Manager will update all those packages on its next update check. But since you already have those installed...